# get HTML element reference from mxCell

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mxgraph

I’ve a HTML String (htmlString) to be added to MXGraph(graph )

var vertex = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, htmlString , x,y, 100, 100);

Now, vertex is mxCell. from vertex how can I get reference of my Dom element?

Comment: Which Dom element? You want to access htmlString that you have added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[graph.convertValueToString](http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.convertValueToString) can return HTML markup or DOM elements directly if [graph.setHtmlLabels(true)](http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.setHtmlLabels) was used. To get a reference to the DOM element for the HTML markup, use `graph.view.getState(vertex).text.node`. DOM elements returned from `convertValueToString` are inserted into the DOM directly.